# OfficeJS Excel Sample error ( _host_Info=Excel )

Tags: office-js

I am trying  to use example with shared folder like this 
https://github.com/OfficeDev/office-js-docs/blob/master/docs/excel/build-your-first-excel-add-in.md

but got a strange error

cannot find 
file://ff/?_host_Info=Excel$Win32$16.01$en-US.
make sure the path or Internet address is correct

Office version 1701 (7066.2092) Desktop Excel32

Answer (score 0):

You should use a web server (local IIS instance, or a node-based dev hosting server, etc.) instead of serving the files off of the file system.

You need the file share for sideloading the manifest on Desktop, but the actual files should be served off of `https://localhost:XXXX`.

For what it's worth, if you're just *starting* with playing around with the Excel APIs, might I recommend [Script Lab](https://aka.ms/scriptlab), a playground experience for learning and trying out the APIs.  It actually has that very same "Getting Started" sample (slightly modified and TypeScript-ified):

[image: Samples list]

[image: Running sample]

Hope you find it useful!

Comment: I did it   But it is workaround . And i need decision for my situation. 
   - use shared folder it's one of availabale method to create AddIn .

Comment: You will need a web server to host the add-in's web content.  The manifest can be sideloaded via a network share, but you need a genuine web environment for the web files.